# Can't find shared libraries in Boost (Linux Mint)

Tags: c++, linux, boost, shared-libraries, linux-mint

I just switched to using Linux Mint and I'm having trouble figuring out the way the default Boost package works on this system. Normally I'd just install a package called `boost`, and `locate` my way to the shared libraries, but on Linux Mint none of that seems to work.

I've done `apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, but I absolutely can't find any of Boost's .so files. Did I install the right package? If so, where are they? I'm especially in need of `libboost_locale.so`.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `dpkg` to examine the contents of the installed package: `dpkg -L libboost-dev-all`.

Comment: Generally correct. But `libboost-all-dev` is a meta package pulling in the others. So it won't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can find them in /usr/lib (like here https://askubuntu.com/questions/263461/where-is-my-boost-lib-file). You can also try

```
apt-cache show libboost-all-dev
```